# How can I activate the previously opened microsoft access instance of an app using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm using this code to open an access database :

```
public partial class Start_Baseet : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
string MyFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Baseet.accde";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application AccApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();

public Start_Baseet()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public void OpenDb()
{
  
        AccApp.Visible = true;
        AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(MyFile, false, "017014a");
        AccApp.RunCommand(AcCommand.acCmdAppMaximize);
        // AccApp.Activate();


    }
}
      

private void Start_Basset_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenDb();
    }
    catch
    {
        AccApp.Quit();
        MessageBox.Show("Something is missing", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }
    finally
    {
        this.Close();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExitThread();
        // Process.GetCurrentProcess().CloseMainWindow();
    }
```

The problem is the `MSACCESS` process is piling up in the running processes so I tried this :

```
  //var prc = Process.GetProcessesByName("MSACCESS.EXE*32");
        var prc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Microsoft Access");
        if (prc.Length > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Access Found");
            SetForegroundWindow(prc[0].MainWindowHandle);
        }
        else
        {
            AccApp.Visible = true;
            AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(MyFile, false, "017014a");
            AccApp.RunCommand(AcCommand.acCmdAppMaximize);
            // AccApp.Activate();


        }
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

But still with every time I use the code another `MSACCESS` process starts.
How can I fix this ?
Other point if I ran my app second time it will open a new instance of the same database can I activate the database if it is opened otherwise open a new instance of it ?
Thanks

Comment: Start_Baseet is a partial class. Is there another class that's being created which in turn is creating a new Access Application?

Comment: That's a windows form , There is a method for creating a new instance of access `OpenDb()`

Comment: You are creating a new Access Object everytime you open a new instance of the form. This could be a dev environment thing. Since Visual Studio doesn't let go of the Access Process properly. You'll have to use Marshal.ReleaseComObject(AccApp); In the form closes event if that's the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This should catch users closing out Access as well through error catching. I'm sure it can be improved on but, I don't get a bunch of MSAccess.exe in the background from this code I wrote a while ago.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application accApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
    private bool isFormClosed = false; 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OpenMicrosoftAccessFile(@"FileName");

        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckIfMSAccessExeIsRunning)); 
        t.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The User Closed Out Access Cleanup.
    /// </summary>
    public void CheckIfMSAccessExeIsRunning()
    {
        int secondsToWait = 5*1000;
        while(!isFormClosed)
        {
            if (accApp != null && 
                accApp.Visible == false)
                CloseMicrosoftAccessFile();
            Thread.Sleep(secondsToWait);
        }
        CloseMicrosoftAccessFile();
    }

    private bool OpenMicrosoftAccessFile(string accessFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (accApp != null &&
                !accApp.Visible)
            {
                CloseMicrosoftAccessFile();
            }

            if (accApp == null)
            {
                accApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();

                accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(accessFileName);

                accApp.Visible = true;
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine((ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException : "");
            CloseMicrosoftAccessFile();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void CloseMicrosoftAccessFile()
    {
        try
        {
            if (accApp != null)
            {
                accApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();
                accApp.Quit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Good chance there never was an Access exe.
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine((ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException : "");
        }
        finally
        {

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(accApp);
            accApp = null;

        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        isFormClosed = true;
    }
}
```

Also, if you still have processes running the Debugger or Visual Studio is probably holding onto it still. It would be good to test this from the release exe. If OpenMicrosoftAccessFile returns false you can try opening it up again but, this way ignores the error it caught.

Comment: I tried but still have the problem , Even sometimes Access doesn't start at all

Comment: I edited the answer a little. I've tested this alone in a newly made application. There are try catches in it so if it's not opening it may be throwing an exception. What does the ex say in the debugger or can you report to console what ex says?

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception it just not open access and it's already in running processes , Even if it opens access it just open new instance of it neglecting what's already opened . I will try your new answer and get back to you , Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to capture an already open access window as an object?

Comment: All I need to do is to open access one time not to have 7 or 8 access processes in the running processes , With every time I use the code another `MSACCESS` process starts. I need to prevent this , For example when the code run it ends all `MSACCESS` hidden processes and open new visible one , Did you get it ? Thanks for your help

Comment: This feels really dirty/smelly but, I think the edit I made will get what you want. When the user closes the program out but, not access it will clear out access too.